# Cannot build torque after moving to ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gcc, g++, torque, ubuntu-18.04

After installing ubuntu 18.04 I cannot build torque software. Ubuntu 16.04 posed no such error.

```
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/socrates/torque-6.1.2/src/lib/Libattr'
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../src/include  -I../../../src/include
`xml2-config --cflags` -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -std=gnu++11  
-g -fstack-protector -Wformat -Wformat-security -DFORTIFY_SOURCE=2
-W -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-long-long -Wpedantic -Werror -Wno-sign-compare
-MT req.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/req.Tpo -c -o req.o req.cpp  

req.cpp: In member function ‘int req::set_from_submission_string(char*, std::__cxx11::string&)’:  
req.cpp:1057:23: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]  

    else if (current != '\0')

                        ^~~~  
Makefile:521: recipe for target 'req.o' failed  
make[4]: *** [req.o] Error 1
```

Comment: It's not only problem if you want to compile torque on 18.04. Torque PBS requires number of dev-libraries to be available on target platform and -std=c++03 if compiled with recent version of gcc/clang. Some of libraries on 18.08 are c++11, so they are incompatible with -std=c++03 requirement and one need to compile all the dependencies as well.

Answer (score 4):

g++ in Ubuntu 16.04 by default is C++03 compiler, if the parameter `-std` does not specify another C++ newer version.
g++ in Ubuntu 18.04 by default is C++14 compiler, there comparison of pointer with `int` (cast from char `'\0'`) is not valid.

I think the code `if (current != '\0')` where `current` is a pointer is suspicious and maybe it's an error. It should be

```
if (*current != '\0')
```

Or

```
if (current != 0)  // before C++11
if (current != nullptr) // since C++11
if (current) // for both before and since C++11
```

It is impossible without context (MCVE) to decide either `current` or `*current` must be used.

**UPDATE**

I looked at torque-6.1.2 code. There is a bug definitely.

```
char       *current;
// ...
this->task_count = strtol(submission_str, &current, 10);
//...
if (*current == ':')
  current++;
else if (current != '\0') // BUG is here, it must be (*current != '\0')
  {
  error = "Invalid task specification";
  return(PBSE_BAD_PARAMETER);
  }
```